# Is there a way to attach an additional value to a key value pair?

Tags: php

I realise the question is not phrased properly, but I'm not sure how else to describe what I mean. Very new to this, so I apologise for any confusion.

I have an array that looks like this:

**Array ( [0] => tomatoes [1] => onions [2] => spinach**

I need to somehow attach a numerical value to each value. For example:
I want tomatoes to have a value of 20, onions 10, and spinach 50.

**Additional info:**

I need to iterate over this array and subtract the values from a database that looks like this:

`+----+-------------+---------+--------+-------+
 | id | name        | type    | amount | unit  |
 +----+-------------+---------+--------+-------+
 |  1 | tomatoes    | veggies |   1000 | grams |
 |  2 | onions      | veggies |   1000 | grams |
 |  3 | spinach     | veggies |   1000 | grams |`

I have tried searching for this, but because I don't know any of the keywords to describe what I'm doing, I may have missed answers that exist on SO. So far, I'm getting the array of veggies as below:

```
<label for="toppingCheckbox">Spinach</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="topping[]" id="toppingCheckbox" value="spinach">
```

I need to attach the numeric value to spinach (in the above example) somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there, as in the form would work you just would be better off using an text/number input field. Then instead of leaving the `topping[]` blank, fill it it instead with the name of the topping:

```
<input type="text" name="topping[spinach]" class="topping" value="">
```

When the user types a value in it and clicks submit, the POST will end up being similar to this:

```
Array
(
    topping[spinach] => {number}
    topping[onions] => {number}
)
```

Then you can loop over the `topping` array:

```
foreach($_POST['topping'] as $topping => $count) {
    // database code subtraction here
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know you could add a key like that and that's precisely what I needed to do to make this work. Thank you so much!